# Print message comes out in batches

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, waits

I have simple query

```
WHILE ( @counter < 50 )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'Counter = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @counter);
        WITH    CTE
                  AS (
                       SELECT TOP 50000 * FROM MyTable
                     )
            DELETE FROM CTE OPTION ( MAXDOP 1 )
        SET @counter += 1
        COMMIT TRAN
    END
```

When I look at messages, the `PRINT` command does not return row every loop but shows up as multiple rows at ones. I have added one line and now it shows up 1 line at the time and the the whole process is much faster.

```
WHILE ( @counter < 50 )
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.5' --< This line
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'Counter = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @counter);
        WITH    CTE
                  AS (
                       SELECT TOP 50000 * FROM MyTable
                     )
            DELETE FROM CTE OPTION ( MAXDOP 1 )
        SET @counter += 1
        COMMIT TRAN
    END
```

so why is it when I have added .5 second wait time to each loop iteration it actually runs faster and allows the print message to come out one at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PRINT` output is buffered.  If you replace `PRINT ...` with `RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` you will see results as they happen.

```
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @counter INT;
WHILE (@counter < 50)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET @msg = 'Counter = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @counter);
    RAISERROR (@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    ;WITH CTE
    AS (
        SELECT TOP(50000) * 
        FROM MySchema.MyTable
        )
    DELETE FROM CTE OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
    SET @counter += 1;
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Comment: So why does adding `WAITFOR DELAY` allows it to come as it happens or close to it?

Comment: I am surmising from the Books Online documentation, where it states that `WAITFOR` runs on a separate thread.  I imagine the context switch to the `WAITFOR` thread flushes the `PRINT` buffer prior to running.  I could easily be wrong.